# c# mvc4 Print to a web browser during long running action

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, actionresult

I have a long running action that runs multiple steps. I would like to output intermediate text to the browser in order to know where the process is, for example

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{
  print("Running step 1"); // to the browser window 
  doStep1();
  print("Running step 2");
  doStep2();
  ...
  ...
  print("Running step n");
  doStepN();
  return View();
}
```

I understand that the text will only show in the browser at "return View(put_the_text_model_here...)". So what I am trying to understand is how I can accomplish this? I guess I have no choice but to use some async JScript function with callbacks, but I am not a web programmer, was hoping there was some quick and dirty way to do this. Are there any templates I can follow?

Comment: `I guess I have no choice but to use some async JScript function with callbacks` - yes, that's what you need. There's no simple way to achieve this. As an alternative you could split the work in multiple actions and then invoke them sequentially using AJAX and display the progress.

Comment: I've seen sites that have "consoles" in the page. How is this done"

Comment: With javascript and asynchronous calls to the server. Or push notifications using WebSockets or similar technology (you may take a look at SignalR).

Comment: anything constuctive?

Comment: You may take a look at SignalR for push notifications.